# Get the second last record from table

Tags: mysql, select

I have tables called `names` and it has only field called `name`. It has the following records in it

```
Ehsan
Malik
Ahmed
Zaryab
Hassan
```

Now, I have to get the second last record (`Zaryab`) from this table. How can I do that?

Comment: What column indicates the order?

Comment: In which basis we can define it second last record ? is there any primary key ?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, there in only one column in the table called 'names'.

Comment: There is no garanteed order without an `order by` clause!

Comment: @Susang No there is no primary key and that is the challenge.

Comment: @juergend exactly, that's the challenge. I wanna know if there is any, any possible of doing this?

Comment: You can select something but there is no garantee that the result is what you want.

Comment: No, there isn't any way. Change the table structure and at least add one primary/unique column which helps to determine the order of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correct, your table doesn't have an id or indexed column. In that case there's not much to do, but to fetch all and get the second last row. However, even if you do that, there is no guarantee that you would get the same result each time.

Comment: So there is no way we can do this without coding? May be with a sub query?

Comment: No, because your table does not have the basic elements like primary key or indicator of an id which you can rely on the ordering of rows.

Comment: @Saani you can't do it. Period. Can's answer says it all.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks for your time.